# Debug firewall hindrance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, azure

I've got a tiny docker container (port 8080) running on an Azure Ubuntu machine setup for me. I'm able to ssh into the machine (port 22), but can't reach the container from the outside (however curling from the machine works). I suspect something to do with firewall, possibly in Azure, possibly on the machine, or somewhere else. How can I find out what's causing the blockage?

I tried setting up a non-docker service on port 80 just to debug stuff. Neither 80 nor 8080 is reachable from the outside.

`netstat` shows this:

```
$ netstat -l -t -n
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

This is what `iptables` looks like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

From my Windows machine at home I ran `tracert`

```
$ tracert [redacted]

Tracing route to [redacted] over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  [redacted] [192.168.1.1]
  2     1 ms     2 ms     1 ms  [redacted].telia.com [x.y.z.1]
  3     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  [redacted].telia.net [x.y.z.87]
  4     8 ms     8 ms    11 ms  [redacted].telia.net [x.y.z.158]
  5     8 ms     9 ms    15 ms  [redacted].telia.net [x.y.z.14]
  6     8 ms    12 ms     7 ms  [redacted].telia.net [x.y.z.179]
  7    10 ms     8 ms     8 ms  [redacted].telia.net [x.y.z.251]
  8    14 ms    18 ms    16 ms  [redacted].msn.net [x.y.z.146]
  9    38 ms    38 ms    38 ms  [redacted].msn.net [x.y.z.250]
 10    38 ms    38 ms    38 ms  [redacted].msn.net [x.y.z.131]
 11    38 ms    38 ms    38 ms  [redacted].msn.net [x.y.z.190]
 12    38 ms    38 ms    38 ms  [redacted].msn.net [x.y.z.214]
 13    37 ms    39 ms    37 ms  [redacted].msn.net [x.y.z.82]
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 ...
```

What else can be done to analyze what's causing the blockage? I've been in this position a number of times, but I've never found a way to find out by myself what the source of the problem is, so would greatly appreciate any help along the way!

Comment: Provide these details: `iptables-save -c` (full firewall rule set), `ip -br a ls` and `ip r ls` (information about network topology and routing). For security reasons you can hide parts of ip addresses in the output. After that, based on this info, I'll write the detailed answer with step-by-step instructions to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Have you checked the network security group attached to your VM or subnet?

Comment: @SamCogan No, but the question was what more I could do to analyze the situation on the network side. This particular issue is now resolved (was Azure firewall), but I'd like to get general information on how I can pinpoint the blockage.